# Magento 2 not able to save or load a custom cache

Tags: magento2, cache

Here is the script (in a shipping module->carrier method, is the cache function can be used in checkout page?), in my custom module

```
$cacheKey = $code;  //e.g ABC

/*saving*/
$cacheData = $request->getPackageWeight().'_'.$request->getDestCountryId().'_'.$code.'='.$totalPostage;

$this->_cacheType->save($cacheData, $cacheKey, [\Testcache\Test\Model\Cache\Type::CACHE_TAG], 86400);
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testcache.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('cacheSave:' . $this->_cacheType->load($cacheKey));
```

cache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd">
    <type name="test_cache" translate="label,description" instance="Testcache\Test\Model\Cache\Type">
        <label>Test Cache type</label>
        <description>Test cache description.</description>
    </type>
</config>
```

Type.php

```
<?php
namespace Testcache\Test\Model\Cache;

/**
 * System / Cache Management / Cache type "Custom Cache Tag"
 */
class Type extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope
{
    /**
     * Cache type code unique among all cache types
     */
    const TYPE_IDENTIFIER = 'test_cache_tag';

    /**
     * Cache tag used to distinguish the cache type from all other cache
     */
    const CACHE_TAG = 'test_cache';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool)
    {
        parent::__construct($cacheFrontendPool->get(self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER), self::CACHE_TAG);
    }
}
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

-------------update--------------
new testing script

```
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {

        $cacheKey = '123123123123123';                
        /*saving*/
        //$cacheData = $request->getPackageWeight().'_'.$request->getDestCountryId().'_'.$code.'='.$totalPostage;
        $cacheData = '123123123132123123123123123';
        $this->_cacheType->save($this->serializer->serialize($cacheData), $cacheKey, [\Testcache\Test\Model\Cache\Type::CACHE_TAG], 86400);
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testcache.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('cacheSave:' . print_r($this->_cacheType->load($cacheKey), true));

.........
```

Answer (score 1):

You should save your data in serialize form.

Inject your custom cache type : `Testcache\Test\Model\Cache\Type` and use it.

```
public function __construct(\Testcache\Test\Model\Cache\Type $cacheType)
{
    $this->_cacheType = $cacheType;
}

// Custom code Inside your function

$this->_cacheType->save(serialize($cacheData), $cacheKey, [\Testcache\Test\Model\Cache\Type::CACHE_TAG], 86400);

$this->_cacheType->load($cacheKey);

$this->_cacheType->test($cacheKey);
```

`$this->_cacheType->load($cacheKey)` will give you the object / array, so use this is in log as

`$logger->info(print_r($this->_cacheType->load($cacheKey), true));`

**Hope  it will help you.**

Comment: Donot use `serialize()` use  `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface:serialize

Comment: Yes use the magento serialize class 
`\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface:serialize`

If this answers is useful then please accept this answer.

Comment: @DJDev it didn't work